# Reference a programmatically created object

Tags: swift, desktop-application

Really struggling to work out how I access an object I create programmatically, from elsewhere in the application. 
I have up until now simply created all my objects in IB and provided them with IBOutlets.

Now i have a need to access this NSRect I have created from an App Delegate method.

```
import Cocoa

class CustomUrlTextField: NSTextField {

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        // create page loading progress indicator
        var progress:CGFloat = 0.5
        var progressrect = NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 2, y: 2), size: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width - 4, height: self.bounds.height - 5))
        progressrect.size.width *= progress
        NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.11, green: 0.43, blue: 0.90, alpha: 1).setFill()
        NSRectFillUsingOperation(progressrect, NSCompositingOperation.CompositeColor)
    }
}
```

So In the App Delegate method I need to do for example:

```
progressrect.size.width = 100
```

but of course I currently have no access to the "progressrect" NSRect object.

EDIT:
Re: Stored Properties answer below. Docs seem to suggest I should already have access to the variables from the app delegate like :

```
var test = CustomUrlTextField()
var theRectTest = test.progressrect.size.width = 100
```

Is that correct? It does not appear to work for me as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out properties and specifically Stored Properties:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_339

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. But I don't seem to be able to access as my edited answer above.

Comment: No, each instance of an object is totally separate. When you initialize the CustomURLTextField in your App Delegate it is not magically connected to the other instance, it is a completely new instance. The point I was trying to make is that your progressrect first needs to be a stored property and not a variable inside of drawRect, then you will need to figure out how to access the text field from your App Delegate as a second step.